# Android - Using Volley to display a custom listview Error in Response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Here I am not getting any response is there anything wrong in this code i had used two parameters in API which i had stored in params though in Error is coming in **new JSONObject(params)**API is working perfectly but
onErrorResponse: Error:

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("employeeId", "dd25ec65-e276-488b-92b1-a324a1d4cc18");
private void getData(){
    //Showing a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

    //Creating a json obj request
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Config.DATA_URL,new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s",response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    //Creating request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Only error in log.

Comment: [ ] url: 0x8ede18 NORMAL null

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use like this:

```
  private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);

        //Creating a json obj request
 StringRequest dataRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.v("Response",response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());

            }
        }){
    @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> sendMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sendMap.put("employeeId", "dd25ec65-e276-488b-92b1-a324a1d4cc18");

                    return sendMap;
                }

    };

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(dataRequest);
    }
```

Let me know if any error u get.....

Comment: here what is map.put? and what to write in new getJSONObject(params)?

Comment: getParam is parameter that map employeeId to your web api

Comment: Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError here mistake is there i mean where should i put (;) ??

Comment: And is this service helpful to load more Data or other method??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126386/discussion-between-manish-and-abhi).